# Python: print each excel row as its own ms word page

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd, python-docx

I've got an excel document with thousands of rows, each row represents a person's record. How can I use Python to extract each row and write that information into an MS Word page?

My goal is to create a doc containing a pseudo-narrative of each record on its own page.

Comment: Good way to waste trees, eh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the content of the Excel file as a Pandas Data Frame and then export the Data Frame into Word Document as a table. This is the generic syntax to achieve your objective

```
import pandas as pd
xls_file = pd.ExcelFile('../data/example.xls')
df = xls_file.parse('Sheet1')

#Needs PyWin32
wordApp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
wordApp.Visible = False
doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(os.getcwd()+'\\template.docx')
rng = doc.Bookmarks("PUTTABLEHERE").Range

# creating Table 
# add one more row in table at word because you want to add column names as header
Table=rng.Tables.Add(rng,NumRows=df.shape[0]+1,NumColumns=df.shape[1])

for col in range(df.shape[1]):        
# Writing column names 
    Table.Cell(1,col+1).Range.Text=str(df.columns[col]) 
    for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    # writing each value of data frame 
        Table.Cell(row+1+1,col+1).Range.Text=str(df.iloc[row,col])
```

Hope this helps!